# How to force explicit namespace usage for request with node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I'm trying to make a SOAP call using the `soap` node module. The problem I'm having is that the service I'm contacting requires explicit namespace usage. Here's how I'm using the module:

```
var soap = require('soap')

soap.createClient('./SessionService.wsdl', function (err, sessionClient) {
   sessionClient.LogIn({
      'Input': {
         'Username': userName,
         'Password': password
      }
   }, function (err, result) {
      // intentionally left blank
   });
});
```

The above code generates the following SOAP envelope. Notice how the Input, Username, and Password elements aren't prefixed with a namespace.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://REDACTED/v2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:q1="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q2="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q3="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q4="http://REDACTED/Service">
   <soap:Body>
      <LogIn xmlns="http://REDACTED/v2">
         <Input>
            <Username>USERNAME</Username>
            <Password>PASSWORD</Password>
         </Input>
      </LogIn>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://REDACTED/v2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:q1="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q2="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q3="http://REDACTED/Service" xmlns:q4="http://REDACTED/Service">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:LogIn xmlns="http://REDACTED/v2">
         <tns:Input>
            <q1:Username>USERNAME</q1:Username>
            <q1:Password>PASSWORD</q1:Password>
         </tns:Input>
      </tns:LogIn>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Are there some undocumented options for producing the proper output? I can get properly namespaced input if I place the namespace in the JavaScript object like so:

```
var soap = require('soap')

soap.createClient('./SessionService.wsdl', function (err, sessionClient) {
    sessionClient.LogIn({
        'tns:Input': {
            'q1:Username': userName,
            'q1:Password': password
        }
    }, function (err, result) {

    });
});
```